# Blank space when Facebook like button count is 0

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

I have added the facebook Like button to my companys web site using the XFBML method. I've set  `send="true"` to show the Send button.

My problem is that when the count is 0 there is a gap between the Like and the Send buttons (where the count goes).  Is there any way of either removing this space or showing the count with a value of 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for removing the space only.

- [Dynamic Facebook Like button width OR show Like count even when there are 0 likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379361/dynamic-facebook-like-button-width-or-show-like-count-even-when-there-are-0-likes)

Sorry, I don't have a solution for show the count with number of Likes = 0.